# How to fill multiple input fields in a template using jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, django-templates, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have been trying to fill ***multiple input fields*** using jquery autocomplete in my Django app.

As an example, my model is somewhat like this:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length=2,  ...) # To store ISO codes
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60,...) # To store country name
```

Now using the following script to call ajax function on an **html template**:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#id_country" ).autocomplete({
        source: "{% url ... %}",
        select: function(e, ui) {
            $("#id_country").val(ui.item.id);
        //  $("#id_country_code_txt").val(ui.item.label);   // I need to populate this input field
            $("#id_country_txt").val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        },
        ...
        ...
    });
});
```

and the following function in my **views.py**:

```
def CountrySearch(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        q = request.GET.get('term','')
        names = Country.objects.filter(name__icontains=q).annotate(value=F('name'), label=F('name')).values('id', 'value', 'label')
        result = list(names)
        data = json.dumps(result)
    mimetype = 'application/json'
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

I am able to fill (*autocomplete*) one of the input fields (refer the ***image*** with fields `id` and `country_name` populated). What I am aiming to do, however, is to fill the other dependent value of `id` (of the `Country` model) as well into input field  `id_country_code_txt` (the field marked with an ***arrow***).

In order to get the value of model field "country_code" (i.e the ISO Code), I added an additional query as below and modified the function to:

```
def CountrySearch(request):
    ...
        ...
        names = Country.objects.filter(name__icontains=q).annotate(value=F('name'), label=F('name')).values('id', 'value', 'label')
        country_codes = Country.objects.filter(country_code__icontains=q).annotate(value=F('country_code'), label=F('country_code')).values('id', 'value', 'label')
        result = list(names) + list(country_codes)
        print('HERE ARE THE results COLLECTED: ' + str(result)) # To see the values being picked up
        ...
        ...
```

In the terminal as I print out the values of the generated list (containing both the fields namely `country_code` and `country_name`), the resultant list is as follows:

```
[
{'id': 2, 'value': 'United States of America', 'label': 'United States of America'}, 
{'id': 2, 'value': 'US', 'label': 'US'}
]
```

What I am struggling to do is to pass the value ***US*** to the input field `id_country_code_txt` marked in the image with an ***arrow***.

Shall appreciate if someone can show me a way how to achive this.

**Edit**:
An image of the fields in the question (part of the form) added. Please have a look.
[image]

Comment: Do not see anything that looks out of place. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Added and image and further clarifications. Please have a look.

Comment: Can you show your html structure

Comment: The `function()` in my question above is part of the html template, which is very basic. Like I have said, I am able to **autocomplete search** on one of the fields, only that I am looking for ways to pick up all related fields' values and populate the relevant fields in the **form**. For **example**, the case would be similar to picking up all relevant **product** information when the user keys in the **product_code**  or **product_name** (as happens in a **POS** or a similar system) and selects one of the results and the underlying values get picked up. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: @user12379095 you will need a complex `source` function that can can identify the field that is being used to initiate the search and then perform a search based on that details.The results can go into all the fields, yet each search will have a unique search term, I. E., a code is different than a name.

Comment: @Twisty I may not have got your drift but on a hunch, went thru' the texts of my question and (it's double _my bad_!!) **found glaring errors**. I have made the changes in the **model class** (where I had the wrong country name field (**country_name** instead of **name**, whichI have corrected now) as well as my ajax function (in **views.py**) (where I had the **result** wrongly showing both the lists generated (where there was in fact **one**). I don't know if I am being clear enough. **PS** I added the 2nd query `country_codes = Country.objects...` to see if the ISO name is being captured.

Comment: @user12379095 as you have not provided any of the HTML, there is no way for anyone to really be able to help and provide suggestions. jQuery is a Client Side scripting language and only works with the HTML Elements on the result page (after it has been sent to the browser from the server). Yes, you want to ensure your Python is returning the correct data, yet without knowing the HTML, it makes it hard to torubleshoot.

Comment: @Twisty Thanks for your reply. Since the template is quite voluminous, could you please suggest the relevant area from where I should reproduce and add in to my question above?

Comment: @user12379095 that should be pretty clear: `#id_country`, `#id_country_code_txt`, and `#id_country_txt`. Possible the parent element too.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following. This is a non-tested example.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".country input").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      // Define default URL base
      var url = "views.py?term=" + request.term;
      var $self = $(".country input:focus");
      // Define the search to use: ID, Code, Name
      switch ($self.attr("id")) {
        case "id_country":
          url += "&queryType=id";
          break;
        case "id_country_code_txt":
          url += "&queryType=code";
          break;
        case "id_country_txt":
          url += "&queryType=name";
          break;
      }
      console.log(url);
      // Perform GET requestfor JSON data
      $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        // Send Data to Autocomplete
        response(data);
      });
    },
    select: function(e, ui) {
      $("#id_country").val(ui.item.id);
      $("#id_country_code_txt").val(ui.item.value);
      $("#id_country_txt").val(ui.item.label);
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.sm {
  width: 4em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="country">
  <label>Country:</label>
  <input id="id_country" class="sm" type="text" />
  <input id="id_country_code_txt" class="sm" type="text" />
  <input id="id_country_txt" type="text" />
</div>
```

Regardless of the Users entry into the fields, Autocomplete will seek results from Python. If there is a unique search page for each type of search, you can assign it in the `switch` along with the other parts of the query.

Each lookup should return the same structure: `[{ id, label, value }]`

When the User selects on of the options, all fields will be populated.

See More:

- https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source
- https://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/
- https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/